# Deserialising unrelated JSON payloads (not polymorphic) on same endpoint

Tags: java, jackson, dropwizard

### Summary

We have an app parsing Jackson payloads based on [Dropwizard](https://www.dropwizard.io/en/latest/). It is receiving JSON payloads that are mapped to various sub-types using `@JsonTypeInfo` on an interface; they all have a similar structure and are well mapped to implementing classes using `@JsonSubTypes`. Now there is a totally unrelated, as in not part of the class hierarchy, JSON structure coming in - how can I handle this?

### Details

I can give concrete details because this is for [Bitbucket webhook event payloads](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/event-payload-938025882.html) which all have a similar structure:

```
{  
  "eventKey":"repo:refs_changed",
  "date":"2017-09-19T09:45:32+1000",
  ... other details
}
```

Where `repo:refs_changed` can also be other kinds of events. Currently I process what we are interested in via this on an interface:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = NAME, property = "eventKey", visible = true)
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = PullRequestEvent.class, name = "pr:opened"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = PullRequestEvent.class, name = "pr:merged"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = PullRequestEvent.class, name = "pr:modified"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = RepositoryEvent.class, name = "repo:refs_changed")
})
public interface Event {
  // ...
}
```

However Bitbucket has a "health check" function when adding a webhook in the repo admin settings page. This simply sends:

```
{"test": true}
```

Since there is no `eventKey` I am not sure how to handle this. I want to just send `200 OK` saying the app is responsive.

One solution that may work is [suppressing the default exception handler](https://groups.google.com/g/dropwizard-user/c/r4-cqhEMjhc) and, somehow, returning `200 OK` just for when the messages is `{"test": true}` otherwise carry on as usual. But throwing this question out here in case there is a more elegant solution.

Comment: If you can manually use the `objectmapper` a solution involving the `jackson` library could be transform the json into a `JsonObjectNode` and check if the eventkey property is present deserializing the json only in this case. If the process instead is automatic or you cannot access the objectmapper then my solution is to be discarded.

Comment: Thanks, I think Dropwizard provides a way of overriding the default mapper used so that such manipulations can be done. I'll look into that while waiting to see what other suggestions there might be.

Comment: Glad to have helped, if Dropwizard provides deserialization features based just on the jackson library there is high possibility you have to set manually the `objectmapper` because there is no std deserialization feature you can use to filter like I described.