# JsonParser reset nextToken() to beginning in ExceptionMapper of type JsonProcessingException

Tags: java, jackson, dropwizard

#### Summary

How do I reset JsonParser's [nextToken()](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonParser.html#nextToken()) back to the start and get the tokens anew? I can't find any promising methods for this.

#### Details

I am creating a custom ExceptionMapper of kind JsonProcessingException to handle a situation where some un-mappable JSON is POSTed to a Jersey endpoint. The `nextToken()` is already "finished" and I can't re-inspect the payload.

I need to do this because it is a health check payload that doesn't conform to the expected JSON structure of the usual API. The contents of the health check payload is not under our control. More context [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73604632/deserialising-unrelated-json-payloads-not-polymorphic-on-same-endpoint) but, basically, we expect this:

```
{  
  "eventKey":"repo:refs_changed",
  "date":"2017-09-19T09:45:32+1000",
  ... other details but eventKey is necessary
}
```

but get this:

```
{"test": true}
```

If I can, in the ExceptionMapper of kind JsonProcessingException, just check for literally `{ "test": true }` and return `200 OK` otherwise the usual 400 error it would be handy.

Comment: Can you maybe share the code/method with the `nextToken()`?

Comment: I want to use the JsonParser [nextToken()](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonParser.html#nextToken()) method as it is intended (via a loop perhaps) but it needs to "go back to the start" in my scenario.

Comment: Hi @Friedrich'Fred'Clausen I am in a similar situation now. Have you managed to find a way to reset the JsonParser back to the start?